# How should I work with multiple make4ht filters?

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

As I use tex4ht/make4ht more, I find I'm building up a collection of my own customisations. To help organise this, is there a recommended way to manage including (multiple) custom filters/domfilters within make4ht?

I know that (specifically for a domfilter) I can make a file `build.lua` with

```
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local process = domfilter {
  -- do stuff here
  return dom
  end
}
Make:match("html$", process)
```

and then run `make4ht -e build.lua`.

But what if I want to have a few different (dom)filters for doing different things? Can I split them out into different files and specify somehow which to run?

Also, is it possible to specify (custom or 'standard') filters to run from within a .sty/.4ht package, or within the .cfg? (I recognise that this could pose a security risk...)

Lots of questions here I'm afraid, but answers to any would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible to modify build sequence from the TeX side, everything needs to be done in Lua files.

You can easily define new DOM filter modules. You just need to use the following name scheme: `domfilters/make4ht-<filtername>.lua`. The `domfilters` directory can be placed in your current directory, but if you want to make it universally available, it is best to place it in your local TEXMF tree, in the `scripts/lua/` directory. For example on my system, it can be `~/texmf/script/lua/domfilters` or `~/texmf/script/lua/make4ht/domfilters`.

DOM filter module should export function that takes the DOM object, makes modifications to it and then return it. See [existing DOM filters](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/tree/master/domfilters) for inspiration.

Sample DOM filter then can look like this (named `~/texmf/scripts/lua/make4ht/domfilters/make4ht-test.lua`):

```lua
return function(dom)
  print "Hello world"
  return dom
end
```

You can require this DOM filter from a build file like this:

```
local domfilters = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local process = domfilters {"test"}
Make:match("html$", process)
```

You can chain multiple filters:

```
local process = domfilters {"test", "fixinlines"}
```

Each step takes DOM object from the previous filter, so you don't need to parse HTML file again.

If you want to make your build sequence available in multiple projects, you have two choices:

1. make4ht configuration file
2. new extension

[make4ht configuration file](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html#x1-250006) is something different than than TeX4ht configuration file (TeX file with `.cfg` extension). It is special Lua build file that can be placed in your home directory or a project root. It should be named `.make4ht`. So you can just take the build file example from the above, rename it to `.make4ht` and put it in any of parent directories of your project and it will be used automatically.

[Extensions](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht/tree/master/extensions) can modify various aspects of the build process. They should be placed in `make4ht/extensions` directory and named as `make4ht-ext-<filename>.lua`. They need to export table with functions, most notably `modify_build`.

Here is a sample extension `make4ht-ext-sample.lua`:

```
local M = {}

local filter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

function M.test(format)
  print("hello format", format)
  return true
end

function M.modify_build(make)
  -- number of filters that should be moved to the beginning
  print "hello modify build"
  local process = filter {"test"}
  make:match("html?$", process)
  return make
end

return M
```

Function `M.test` takes current output format and decides if the extension should be executed or not. Some extension support only HTML for example, so this function then returns `false` and it is not used at all.

Function `M.modify_build` can contain similar code as build files, but `make4ht` variable, passed as a parameter, is used  instead of the global `Make4ht` object that is used in the ordinary build files.

Extension can be required using the `f` parameter of `make4ht`, like

```
make4ht -f html5+sample filename.tex
```

Output of this command is:

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: sample.tex
hello format    html5
hello modify build
Hello world
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

Comment: Thanks for this very nice explanation. Two questions. 1: In your extension version you have `make:match("html?$", process)` – does the `?` do something there? What is the `match` matching against, filenames? 2: It seems that when I use the make4ht config, my filters get run before common_domfilters (if using -f html5, that is), whereas if I use the extension, they run after. What determines the order of processing?

Comment: @AlexWatson yes, names of output files are used. the `?` is used because one user uses `.htm` extension, so this regular expression matches both `.html` and `.htm`.

Comment: @AlexWatson config file is processed before extensions are registered, so filters that you register here have priority. note that extensions can modify the build files and some of them insert their filters at the beginning of the build sequence. extensions required from the command line are registered after default extensions, so they are always processed after them.

Comment: OK - so just to check I understood, when domfilter{...} is run, ... is put into a table of domfilters to be run at the end -- probably in order, but maybe not if an extension messes with it by hand? Presumably all this is done at the end, after the htm(l) file is made by tex4ht?

Comment: @AlexWatson yes, filters are normally put to build sequence table in the order when they are requested. build sequence is created before compilation starts, because extensions can modify not only filters, but they also can add new commands to be executed (tidy, for example).