# MathML as well need LaTeX coding in tex4ht

Tags: luatex, mathml

I would like to convert the below file to `MathML` format as well need the `LaTeX` coding in `MathML` Semantic tag.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\article{Article Title Here}
\author{Author Name Here}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is the sample paragraph.
 \begin{equation}\label{eq1-11}
T\,^{\prime}_{\mu \nu} = \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha} {\partial\xi^{\prime\mu}}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial \xi^{\prime\nu}} \right) T_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}

Please refer the equations \ref{eq1-11} for the further testing.
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, I am a bit busy right now, so I cannot test it. I did some tests in this area some time ago: https://github.com/michal-h21/mathdimen . I don't know if it still works, as I said it is quite old.

Comment: Must it be tex4ht?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227195/107497 gives that as an option, plus pandoc, latexml, and a link to a website with dozens of other options.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible approaches how to achieve this:

1. configure TeX4ht to catch all math content and typeset it twice - once using MathML, second time as a verbatim text.
2. parse MathML content and convert it back to the LaTeX code
3. pre-process the input TeX file and modify it in the way it will be easier for working with

The first method could reuse the code that we use for the MathJax option in TeX4ht, see file `mathjax-latex-4ht.4ht` for details.

The second method won't produce the same LaTeX code as was the original input. It may be a problem for you. LuaXML can be used [for the conversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548484/2891).

I will present the third method in my answer. It consists of two components - the input filter that parses the input LaTeX file for the math content and marks it with some additional macros, and make4ht DOM filter that modifies the resulting HTML file to produce the correct MathML structure.

Here is the input filter. It reads input from the standard input and prints the modified output.

File `altmath.lua`:

```lua
-- insert envrionmnets that should be handled by the script here
local math_environments = {
  equation = true,
  displaymath = true,
  ["equation*"] = true,

}

-- macros that will be inserted to the updated document
local macros = [[
\NewDocumentCommand\inlinemath {mv} {\HCode{<span class="inlinemath">}#1\HCode{<span class="alt">}\NoFonts #2\EndNoFonts\HCode{</span></span>}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{altdisplaymath}{} {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="altmath">}} {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
]]

-- we will insert macros before the second control sequence (we assume that first is \documentclass
local cs_counter = 0

-- we will hanlde inline and diplay math differently
local inline  = 1
local display = 2

local function handle_math(input, nexts, stop, buffer, mathtype)
  local content = input:sub(nexts, stop)
  local format = "\\inlinemath{%s}{%s}" -- format used to insert math content back to the doc
  -- set format for display math
  if mathtype == display then
    format = [[
\begin{altdisplaymath}
%s
\begin{verbatim}
%s
\end{verbatim}
\end{altdisplaymath}
]]
  end
  buffer[#buffer + 1] =  string.format(format, content, content )
end

local function find_next(input, start, buffer)
  -- find next cs or math start
  local nexts, stop = input:find("[$\\]", start)
  local mathtype   
  if nexts then
    -- save current text chunk from the input buffer
    buffer[#buffer+1] = input:sub(start, nexts - 1)
    local kind, nextc = input:match("(.)(.)", nexts)
    if kind == "\\" then -- handle cs
      -- insert our custom TeX macros before second control sequence
      cs_counter = cs_counter + 1
      if cs_counter == 2 then
        buffer[#buffer+1] = macros
      end
      if nextc == "(" then -- inline math
        _, stop = input:find("\\)", nexts)
        mathtype = inline
      elseif nextc == "[" then -- display math
        _, stop = input:find("\\]", nexts)
        mathtype = display
      else -- maybe environment?
        -- find environment name
        local env_name = input:match("^begin%s*{(.-)}", nexts+1)
        -- it must be enabled as math environment
        if env_name and math_environments[env_name] then
          _, stop = input:find("\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}", nexts)
          mathtype = display
        else -- not math environment 
          buffer[#buffer+1] = "\\" -- save backspace that was eaten by the processor
          return stop + 1 -- return back to the main loop
        end
      end
    else -- handle $
      if nextc == "$" then -- display math
        _, stop = input:find("%$%$", nexts + 1)
        mathtype = display
      else -- inline math
        _, stop = input:find("%$", nexts + 1)
        mathtype = inline
      end
    end
    if not stop then -- something failed, move one char next
      return nexts + 1
    end
    -- save math  content to the buffer
    handle_math(input, nexts, stop, buffer, mathtype)
  else
    -- if we cannot find any more cs or math, we need to insert rest of the input 
    -- to the output buffer
    buffer[#buffer+1] = input:sub(start, string.len(input))
    return nil
  end
  return stop + 1
end

-- process the input buffer, detect inline and display math and also math environments
local function process(input)
  local buffer = {} -- buffer where text chunks are stored
  local start = 1
  start = find_next(input, start,buffer)
  while start do
    start = find_next(input, start, buffer)
  end
  return table.concat(buffer) -- convert output buffer to string
end


local content = io.read("*all")
print(process(content))
```

You can test it using the following command:

```
texlua altmath.lua < sample.tex
```

This is modified version of your original TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand\inlinemath {mv} {\HCode{<span class="inlinemath">}#1\HCode{<span class="alt">}\NoFonts #2\EndNoFonts\HCode{</span></span>}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{altdisplaymath}{} {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="altmath">}} {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\title{Article Title Here}
\author{Author Name Here}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is the sample paragraph with \inlinemath{$a=b^2$}{$a=b^2$} inline math. Different \inlinemath{\(a=c^2\)}{\(a=c^2\)} type of math.
 \begin{altdisplaymath}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1-11}
T\,^{\prime}_{\mu \nu} = \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha} {\partial\xi^{\prime\mu}}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial \xi^{\prime\nu}} \right) T_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1-11}
T\,^{\prime}_{\mu \nu} = \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha} {\partial\xi^{\prime\mu}}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial \xi^{\prime\nu}} \right) T_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}
\end{verbatim}
\end{altdisplaymath}


Please refer the equations \ref{eq1-11} for the further testing.
\end{document}
```

You can see that it inserts macro definitions after the `\documentclass` command. It defines the `\inlinemath` command and `altdisplaymath` environment. The definitions contain code that inserts HTML tags directly to the converted file. They are designed to be used just with TeX4ht.

You can convert your file to HTML using

```
texlua altmath.lua < sample.tex | make4ht -j sample - "mathml"
```

It produces a following code:

```html
<span class='inlinemath'><!-- l. 14 --><math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' display='inline'><mi>a</mi> <mo class='MathClass-rel'>=</mo> <msup><mrow><mi>b</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></msup></math><span class='alt'>$a=b^2$</span></span>
```

or

```html
<div class='altmath'> <!-- tex4ht:inline --><table class='equation'><tr><td>
<!-- l. 16 --><math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' display='block' class='equation'>
                       <mstyle class='label' id='x1-1001r1'></mstyle><!-- endlabel --><mi>T</mi><msubsup><mrow><mspace width='0.17em' class='thinspace'></mspace></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>μν</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>′</mi></mrow></msubsup> <mo class='MathClass-rel'>=</mo> <mrow><mo form='prefix' fence='true'> (</mo><mrow> <mfrac><mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>α</mi></mrow></msup></mrow>
<mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>′μ</mi></mrow></msup></mrow></mfrac> </mrow><mo form='postfix' fence='true'>)</mo></mrow> <mrow><mo form='prefix' fence='true'> (</mo><mrow> <mfrac><mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>β</mi></mrow></msup></mrow>
<mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>′ν</mi></mrow></msup></mrow></mfrac> </mrow><mo form='postfix' fence='true'>)</mo></mrow> <msub><mrow><mi>T</mi></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>αβ</mi></mrow></msub>
</math></td><td class='eq-no'>(1)</td></tr></table>
<!-- l. 18 --><p class='nopar'>

</p>
   <pre id='verbatim-1' class='verbatim'>
\begin{equation}\label{eq1-11}
T\,^{\prime}_{\mu \nu} = \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha} {\partial\xi^{\prime\mu}}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial \xi^{\prime\nu}} \right) T_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}
</pre>
<!-- l. 23 --><p class='nopar'> </p></div>
```

We need to use make4ht DOM filter to create a correct MathML structure. Save the following file as `build.lua`:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

-- find mathml and insert TeX as an alternative annotation
local function update_mathml(element, class)
  local alt_element_t = element:query_selector(class)
  if not alt_element_t and not alt_element_t[1] then return nil end
  -- save alt element contents and remove it from the document
  local alt_contents = alt_element_t[1]:get_children()
  alt_element_t[1]:remove_node()
  -- create a new structure of the mathml element ->
  -- mathml 
  --   semantics
  --     mrow -> math content
  --     annotation -> saved TeX
  local mathml = element:query_selector("math")[1]
  local mathml_contents = mathml:get_children()
  local semantics = mathml:create_element("semantics")
  local mrow = semantics:create_element("mrow")
  mrow._children = mathml_contents -- this trick places saved original mathml content into a new <mrow>
  semantics:add_child_node(mrow)
  local annotation = semantics:create_element("annotation", {encoding="application/x-tex"})
  annotation._children = alt_contents
  semantics:add_child_node(annotation)
  mathml._children = {semantics}
end

local process = domfilter {
  function(dom)
    for _, inline in ipairs(dom:query_selector(".inlinemath")) do
      update_mathml(inline, ".alt")
    end
    for _, display in ipairs(dom:query_selector(".altmath")) do
      update_mathml(display, ".verbatim")
    end
    return dom
  end
}
```

It parses the HTML files for our custom `<span>` and `<div>` elements, get the alt text and inserts it as an '` element of the MathML code.

This is the result:

```html
   <h3 class='sectionHead'><span class='titlemark'>1   </span> <a id='x1-10001'></a>Introduction</h3>
<!-- l. 14 --><p class='noindent'>This  is  the  sample  paragraph  with
<span class='inlinemath'><!-- l. 14 --><math display='inline' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><semantics><mrow><mi>a</mi> <mo class='MathClass-rel'>=</mo> <msup><mrow><mi>b</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></msup></mrow><annotation encoding='application/x-tex'>$a=b^2$</annotation></semantics></math></span> inline math.
Different <span class='inlinemath'><!-- l. 14 --><math display='inline' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><semantics><mrow><mrow><mi>a</mi> <mo class='MathClass-rel'>=</mo> <msup><mrow><mi>c</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></msup></mrow></mrow><annotation encoding='application/x-tex'>\(a=c^2\)</annotation></semantics></math></span>
type of math. </p><div class='altmath'> <!-- tex4ht:inline --><table class='equation'><tr><td>
<!-- l. 16 --><math class='equation' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' display='block'><semantics><mrow>
                       <mstyle id='x1-1001r1' class='label'></mstyle><!-- endlabel --><mi>T</mi><msubsup><mrow><mspace width='0.17em' class='thinspace'></mspace></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>μν</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>′</mi></mrow></msubsup> <mo class='MathClass-rel'>=</mo> <mrow><mo fence='true' form='prefix'> (</mo><mrow> <mfrac><mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>α</mi></mrow></msup></mrow>
<mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>′μ</mi></mrow></msup></mrow></mfrac> </mrow><mo fence='true' form='postfix'>)</mo></mrow> <mrow><mo fence='true' form='prefix'> (</mo><mrow> <mfrac><mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>β</mi></mrow></msup></mrow>
<mrow><mi>∂</mi><msup><mrow><mi>ξ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>′ν</mi></mrow></msup></mrow></mfrac> </mrow><mo fence='true' form='postfix'>)</mo></mrow> <msub><mrow><mi>T</mi></mrow><mrow><mi mathvariant='italic'>αβ</mi></mrow></msub>
</mrow><annotation encoding='application/x-tex'>
\begin{equation}\label{eq1-11}
T\,^{\prime}_{\mu \nu} = \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\alpha} {\partial\xi^{\prime\mu}}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \xi^\beta}{\partial \xi^{\prime\nu}} \right) T_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}
</annotation></semantics></math></td><td class='eq-no'>(1)</td></tr></table>
<!-- l. 18 --><p class='nopar'>

</p>
   
<!-- l. 23 --><p class='nopar'> </p></div>
```

Comment: Awesome... Is it possible to get both `MathML` and `LaTeX` tags by using `htlatex`? in a same file?

Comment: @MadyYuvi this could work with `htlatex` as well. in theory. You would need to make temporary TeX file, because `htlatex` doesn't support pipes. YOu would also need to post-process the HTML file with the DOM filter. But anyway, `htlatex` is officially obsolete, because `make4ht` does lot of fixes on the generated HTML file. Including fixes on MathML. You most likely don't get correct MathML elements with `htlatex` only.

Answer (score 0):

Provided `MWE` having many LaTeX coding errors, I've fixed and the modified tags are:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\title{Article Title Here}

\author{Author Name Here}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is the sample paragraph.
\begin{equation}\label{eq1-11}
T\,^{\prime}_{\mu \nu} = \left( \frac{\partial \xi^{\alpha}}
{\partial\xi^{\prime\mu}}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \xi^{\beta}}{\partial \xi^{\prime\nu}} \right) T_{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}

Please refer the equations \ref{eq1-11} for the further testing.
\end{document}
```

After correct the errors, I've run the command

`htlatex test "xhtml,mathml,mathml-" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"`

It converts nicely...

**EDIT**

If you need to get display the `LaTeX` tags in the converted `HTML`, then use the below `.cfg` file:

****conversion.cfg****

```
\RequirePackage{verbatim,etoolbox}

\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\AltMathOne#1${\HCode{\detokenize{\(#1\)}}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMathOne} 
\def\AltlMath#1\){\HCode{\detokenize{\(#1\)}}\)}
\Configure{()}{\AltlMath}{}
\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\HCode{\detokenize{\[#1\]}}\]}
\Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
\def\AltDisplayOne#1#2$${#1\HCode{\detokenize{$$#2$$}}$$}
\Configure{$$}{}{}{\AltDisplayOne}{}{}
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
\ifcsdef{#1}{%
  \renewenvironment{#1}{%
    \NoFonts%
  \Configure{verbatim}{}{} % suppress <br /> tags
    \texttt{\string\begin\{#1\}}\HCode{\Hnewline}% we need to use \texttt to get all characters right
      \verbatim}{\endverbatim\texttt{\string\end\{#1\}}\EndNoFonts}%
}{}%
}
\VerbMath{align}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{equation*}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

---

Then the run command:

```
htlatex sample "conversion" " " "-cvalidate -p"
```

Comment: What are the "many" coding errors? I see only `\article` instead of `\title`...

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Thanks for your reply. But i expecting mathml coding as well input `LaTeX` Coding also. In your example i have found only Mathml and not found LaTeX coding.

Comment: @campa I've modified `OP's` question and removed those errors...

Comment: What I meant is that (1) when you correct errors it would be helpful if you would describe them in the answer, and (2) you keep talking about errors (plural) while I see only one. (A couple of questionable other things, yes, but only one real error.)

Comment: @MadyUuvi: How to get both `MathML` output and `LaTeX` output in the html file? Please advise.

Comment: @Balaji It is possible by getting `TeX code` and `MathML` code separately, but not sure about both will be in a same file....Trying...

Comment: @MadyYuvi: TeX code and MathML Code separately also it's enough and good for me and waiting for your reply.

Comment: @Balaji Check the modified suggestion....

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Now i have getting only LaTeX coding. I have changed "\Preamble{mathml,-cunihtf,-utf8,mathjax,html5,early_,early^,ext=html}" then also mathml is not display. Why and how do get both in the same html file.

Comment: @Balaji I've already told that I'm not sure about to get both `LaTeX` and `MathML` tags in a same output `HTML` file...

Comment: It should be possible to reuse code from the TeX4ht code for MathJax output to output both LaTeX and MathML. But I don't think it will be too easy. Another option is to parse MathML back to LaTeX using make4ht DOM filters. It won't be easy either.

Comment: @Mady: But in the `latexml` another script is possible to get both mathml as well latex output. Why this is not possible in our tex4ht? Any ideas...

Comment: @Balaji `latexml` is purely based on `Perl' script, but `TeX4ht' is not like that...

Comment: @michal: Any best tutorial about you know make4ht DOM filters with examples. I will try to study and do something about my requirements.

Comment: Actually `tex4ht` is very good and give good results. some equations only not converting like `a_\mathit` and user defined macros... We are worry about this... Otherwise tex4ht is very good compare with latexml

Comment: @Balaji see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548484/2891 for example of mathml parsing using LuaXML. it would need to be adapted for make4ht dom filters, of course. some info about DOM filters is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564006/2891